# `name` as a variable name in freemarker breaks

Tags: java, maven, freemarker, spark-java

I have the following code in an ftl:

```
<#macro field label name value="" type="text">
    ${name}
    ${name!"print if null"}
    <div class="field">
        <div class="clearfix" id="${name}_field">
            <label for="${name}">${label}</label>
            <div class="input">
            <input type="${type}" id="${name}" name="${name}" value="${value}">
                <span class="help-inline"></span>
                <span class="help-block"></span> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</#macro>


<@field label="label" name="test" />
```

And this is printing this:

```
foo-test
test
<div class="field">
    <div class="clearfix" id="foo-test_field">
        <label for="foo-test">label</label>
        <div class="input">
        <input type="text" id="foo-test" name="foo-test" value="">
            <span class="help-inline"></span>
            <span class="help-block"></span> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`foo-test` is the name of my app but can't understand why is it being printed there.. Just used ctrl+f to search for `foo-test` and it is nowhere in the ftl or the controller...

Besides this, let's suppose that `name` is a variable that has the name of my app.. Then why the second print just prints the right value that i passed to my macro?? This is really strange...

I use Maven and spark so I have this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-template-freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The plugins are this:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources> 
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.foo.foo-test</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
    .....

    import spark.ModelAndView;
    import spark.Spark;
    import spark.template.freemarker.FreeMarkerEngine;

    ......

    Spark.get("/foo", (request, response) -> {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        return new ModelAndView(attributes, "test.ftl");
    }, new FreeMarkerEngine());
```

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: @AleksandrM yes, does it have something to do with this?

Comment: How do you packaging/including your ftl-s in maven? Can you show your pom.xml?

Comment: @AleksandrM I just updated the question with the information

Comment: Show your pom `plugins` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have configured maven to filter your resources, which it does substituting `${name}` placeholder with the name of your project.

Remove `<resources>` from your pom or if you do need resource filtering you can exclude ftl-s files.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

BTW the `maven-resources-plugin` documentation about [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) demonstrates exact this behaviour with the `${name}` placeholder. :)

Comment: That was it ! Can't believe that Maven was doing this.. And can't understand why did only happen inside macros.. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Very strange... it should work, and works for me. I suspect that something search-and-replaces `${name}` in that template before FreeMarker parses it (custom `TemplateLoader`-s can do that for example). Like, what happens if you write `${name<#-- just a comment -->}` instead of `${name}`?

Comment: You are right. If i write `${name<#-- just a comment -->}` then it prints what I want.. But if print `${name}` just in the first line it throws an error that name is undefined.. Why does this only happen inside the macro??

Comment: I don't know what magic was applied on the template file before FreeMarker gets it... Can you do a `System.out.println(template)` where `template` is the `fremarker.template.Template` object to see what's inside the template? Also, what FreeMarker version is that (`${.version}`)? I hope not some preview release from 10 years ago...

Comment: Or rather, `System.out.println(template.getSource())`.

Comment: Version prints `2.3.19` and for the template, I don't know where to get the template because it is embed inside the spark-template-freemarker..

Comment: 2.3.19 is an outdated but otherwise stable version, so that's not the problem. As of how to get hold of the `Template` object, you can do a hack: implement `TemplateDirectiveModel`, and there you can get it from `env.getTemplate()` (at least if it's the top-level template), and print the result to the `env.getOut()` `Writer`. Then in the template you invoke this directive like `<@'com.example.YourDirective'?new() />`.